# Why are there two precisions and two recalls?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, nltk, precision, precision-recall

I am running Naive Bayes classifier using Python, Pandas, and NLTK.

I understand what and how to calculate precision and recall in general, but I don't understand why there are one pair of precisions and one pair of recalls when using the following commands

```
from featx import precision_recall
nb_precisions, nb_recalls = precision_recall(nb_classifier, test_feats)

training_n = int(data_n * 0.25) ### changeable
featuresets = [(first_letter(name), ethnicity) for index, (name, ethnicity, last_name) in df.iterrows()] ### changeable
train_feats, test_feats = featuresets[training_n:], featuresets[:training_n] 

nb_classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_feats)

# Performance
print "Accuracy: " + str(accuracy(nb_classifier, test_feats))

# Precision and recall
nb_precisions, nb_recalls = precision_recall(nb_classifier, test_feats)
print "Precision +: " + str(nb_precisions[ethnic_target1])
print "Precision -: " + str(nb_precisions[ethnic_non_target])
print "Recall +: " + str(nb_recalls[ethnic_target1])
print "Recall -: " + str(nb_recalls[ethnic_non_target])

Accuracy: 0.99632
Precision +: None
Precision -: 0.99632
Recall +: 0.0
Recall -: 1.0
```

The classification is Chinese vs non-Chinese using the first letter of people's name (feature).

```
                                     Gold standard
                              Chinese         non-Chinese
Predicted      Chinese            A                C
               non-Chinese        B                D
```

My understanding is precision = A/(A+C)
and recall = D/(B+D)

Comment: `+` and `-`. Those are the positive and negative examples. What you see are the precision and recall values for positive classification and negative classification.

Comment: Hi I have added some 2x2 table to help illustrate, could you refer to the A, B, C, D with formulas of what you mean by positive and negative classifications? Thanks.

Comment: `Precision(Chinese) = A / ( A + C) , Recall(Chinese) = A / (A + B) `, `Precision(Non-Chinese) = D / (B + D), Recall(Non-Chinese) = D / (D + C)`

Comment: Note for Chinese, Prediction of `C` is a false positive. Prediction of `B` is a false-negative.  While for Non-Chinese, Prediction of `D` is a true-positive, Prediction of `C` is a false -negative, prediction of B is a false-positive, etc.